# Jenkins doesn't commit the approvals

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

We have Jenkins where users are getting below error while running their pipeline:

```
Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] echo
Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String
Scripts not permitted to use method java.lang.Throwable printStackTrace. Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.
[Pipeline] fileExists
[Pipeline] echo
org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use method java.lang.Throwable printStackTrace
```

Earlier they bypassed the security by adding the repository in the global library, however, now they want to load the library through their pipeline. But now, every time I'm approving the below signatures:

```
signature : method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.steps.build.RunWrapper getRawBuild

signature : new java.io.File java.lang.String

signature : method java.lang.Throwable printStackTrace

signature : method org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.support.actions.EnvironmentAction getEnvironment
```

On the next run, it's still asking for the same approvals, the pipeline is failing with the same error.

Jenkins runs on VM with version 2.204.4

Comment: In our experience, it's once per method; when you approve a method once, it's never asking again for that specific method. (Different parameters make for different methods, though.) Is your experience different, where it asks for approval on the methods already approved?

Comment: Asks for the same. I added more details in the question

Comment: After your update, it seems like a different method. You need to cycle through "trigger-approve" until all the methods are approved.

Comment: No, it's keep showing the same signature

Comment: Check that these signatures are in the approved list after you approve them.

Comment: Yes I do, but it's still popup every run and pipeline fails

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing Permissive-script-security plugin and restart Jenkins, solved the issue